# What is a satisfiable approach to let a computed value to wait for asynchronous data in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Let's say I get a products list from my state manager inside my Vue.js component and a computed property needs that list to process it. Finally, my DOM depends on the proceeded list.

```
<template>
  <span>{{ computedproducts }}</span>
</template>

<script>
export default {

  created () {
    this.$store.dispatch('getProducts')
  },

  computed: {
    products () {
      // Following is asynchronous
      return this.$store.state.products
    },

    computedProducts () {
      // Processing products in some way
      return this.products
    }

  }
}
</script>
```

With this I get an error because the `computedProducts` doesn't exist at start.

A possible solution would be to set:

```
<span v-if="products.length > 0">{{ computedproducts }}</span>
```

And also return a Promise from the products state and process the products at the `created` hook. But it feels hacked. Is there a better approach?

Comment: Depends who you're trying to satisfy, I suppose...

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return { products: [] }
  },

  created () {
    this.$store.dispatch('getProducts').then(res => { this.products = res })
  },

  computed: {
    computedProducts () {
      // Processing products in some way
      return this.products
    }
  }
}
```

**[Live Demo.](https://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/416oz6ga/)**

Comment: This looks very promising. Thank you very much! That means that computedProducts waits for the data array, is this correct?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. The computed property still can't access the asynchronous product list because it's not loaded yet.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. The problem is that I always have to take care of the dummy data (in your case "followers: 0"). Imagine there is a nested array I would need to maintain both, the one inside the vuex store and the one inside all components.